# Can't add a PPA, stuck at gpg: keybox

Tags: apt, php, ppa

I'm on Debian Testing and I'm trying to add a repository with this command:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

But it eventually gets stuck after it adds the gpg key, like so:

`gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp8mhc0b4f/pubring.gpg' created`

Any idea what's causing this? Is it a possible package conflict?

Comment: IIRC, the *PPA* spec is a Ubuntu non-Debian sort of thing.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you probably don't need this ppa when using debian testing.

Comment: I'm having similar issue on Debian Stretch. After importing an apt key a process like `dirmngr --daemon --homedir /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DhIfVNmEPx` remains stuck. Here's [possibly related Debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=840997).